# In drupal Primary Link is like empty

Tags: drupal-6

I'm making a webpage in Drupal 6.26, and I blocked in a strange thing. I develop both in Localhost, and online, and the strange is that some how in online the primary links are empty (but there's element on it I can see in /admin/build/menu-customize/primary-links also in this page the menu elements appeared in the place, but in the other pages they don't), but in Localhost everything is ok, and i checked all of the settings and they are the same, the theme files are the same to,(and i didn't change anything in the other drupal files), the only difference is that the online page is set in offline (because the under maintenance), and I tried it to make it online, but the problem is still there, so I don't really have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a theme problem. Make sure your local configuration has the same active theme as the installation on the public server. Try switching to a default theme that comes with Drupal.

Another cause might be one of your modules. Try disabling all but the system modules and then start re-enabling them one-by-one to see which one changes your menu.